# using subquery in CTE in sql alchemy in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, common-table-expression

I have given a task to convert a query which is in zsql to sql alchemy which has a CTE with sub-queries. I converted, but when i generate the converted query, the arguments are not being passed correctly.For example, in below part

```sql
FROM   table1
JOIN  table2
 ON     table1.col1 = table2.col2
  AND    table1.col3 = 'Y'
```

Here, the col3 = 'Y' should be an integer value and it is printing correctly in sub-query, but when i integrate with cte, it is causing this issue.

The structure of my query is as below,

```sql
With cteqry as (Select ...
left join (subquery1)
left join (subquery2)
)

Select cteqry .*, ...
```

The Python code to execute the above query is as below,

```
sub_queryobj1 = (self.session.query(db.Table2.col2).filter(idn == 20))
   
    enc_proc_main_ct = (self.session.query(db.Table1.col1, ..
                                               ).outerjoin (sub_queryobj1, (db.Table1.col1 == sub_queryobj1.c.col1)
    
    )
```

Here,
enc_proc_main_ct is the cte query object having the sub-query object enc_proc_main_ct inside that

Comment: you need to paste your python  code to see what's happening there

Comment: @eshirvana, I jhave added python code

Comment: are you sure you paste the whole code? I don't see where you pass the value for col3